# Is there an equivalent of _mm_slli_si128(__m128i a, int num) for floats?

Tags: c, x86, vectorization, sse, intrinsics

Let's say I have a vector of 4 floats:

```
__m128 vector = |f0|f1|f2|f3| (pseudocode)
```

My intention is to transform that variable into this:

```
|0.0|f0|f1|f2|
```

Doing a shift right would appear to be the simplest choice, but I haven't been able to find such an intrinsic available for floats.

What would be the fastest way to accomplish this?

Comment: `_mm_shuffle_ps` + `_mm_and_ps`

Comment: I have done this and the principle works. However, I am not sure as to what values I should input as parameters to keep the last floating point numbers: vb = _mm_and_ps(vb, _mm_set_ps(?, ?, ?, 0)).

Comment: An alternative is to use two casts: `_mm_castsi128_ps` and `_mm_castps_si128`, so that you can still use '_mm_slli_si128' . These casts do not generate any instructions. The only penalty is a small latency increase from going from the float to the integer domain and vice versa.

Comment: wim's suggestion of still using an integer byte-shift might cost 1 cycle of bypass latency before and after, if used between two FP math instructions.  But the alternative uses and `andps` which itself has latency.  And on Intel Sandybridge family, SIMD-integer shuffles don't have any bypass latency when used between SIMD-FP instructions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my solution:

```
__m128 const mask = _mm_castsi128_ps(_mm_set_epi32(0, -1, -1, -1));

vector = _mm_shuffle_ps(vector, vector, _MM_SHUFFLE(0,3,2,1))
vector = _mm_and_ps(vector, mask);
```